# Controlled Ry gate on IBM and IonQ basis gates

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, ibm-q-experience, transpile, ionq

As far as I know the basis gates for IBM and IonQ are:

IBM: ['cx', 'id', 'rz', 'x', 'sx']

IonQ: ['rx', 'ry', 'rz', 'rxx', 'id']

I used qiskit.transpile to see check how Controlled Ry gate can be decomposed into each basis gates, where the results are as below.

Circuit without transpile:

[image: strong text]

IBM basis gates transpile:

[image]

IonQ basis gates transpile:

[image]

As I know, one advantageous feature of IonQ is that it can construct CRx or CRz with only 1 entanglement gate. Does only CRy gate requires 2 entanglement gate or does the transpiled result is not fully optimized?